# How to do delete folder or file through requests s3 in digitalocean space

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I trying to handle a great service called Space in Digital Ocean. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-file-to-object-storage-with-node-js) is a pretty nice explanation about uploading files, but there is only about GET request and nothing about DELETE. Maybe someone has got experience with S3 together with Digital Ocean Space on Node JS?

Using localhost server I found out in settings of Space that "Advanced CORS Options" you can provide "Origin" and only "Allowed Methods" GET.
But PUT, DELETE, POST, HEAD is disable.

Here is what I trying:

```
export default {
  upload: (req, res) => {
    const storage = multerS3({
      s3,
      bucket,
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
      acl: 'public-read',
      key: function(req, file, callback) {
        const { email } = req.user;

        callback(null, email + '/' + file.originalName);
      },
    });

    const upload = multer({ storage }).array('upload', 3);

    upload(req, res, err => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          errors: [{ title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message }],
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Success upload file');
      }
      res.end();
    });
  },

  delete: (req, res) => {
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: 'some-folder-name-here' };
    s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({ error: err });
      }
      res.send({ data });
    });
  }
}
```

Actually it should be great if it's gonna be possible to delete and upload files through my localhost using simple s3 api.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Mistake was here: `s3.deleteObjects`, have to use `s3.deleteObject`, and yes, have to use in `Key` whole path without bucket name.
Perfect explain [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/digital-ocean-spaces-pros-cons-and-how-to-use-it-with-javascript-1802559ce2bd). Thanks everyone.

Comment: what error are you getting here?

Comment: your script do seem fine just this part `Key: 'some-folder-name-here'`  it's not some folder name, it's the whole key as in where to locate the file. Also, do not need to set up anything to do with CORS in bucket.  Get an IAM, and use the access key and secret key to access the bucket locally

Comment: @Tsuna IAM and access key put there, my GET upload works very well, question only about DELETE request. So, there is wrong Key? You said "the whole key as in where to locate the fil". But it's have to be whole path? Something like:
{Bucket: 'Name_of_my_baket', Key: 'mainFolder/subFolder/fileName.jpg'}
Some thing like this? Do you have example? thank you!

Comment: yes that's what I meant the whole path as you mentioned ` {Bucket: 'Name_of_my_baket', Key: 'mainFolder/subFolder/fileName.jpg'}` when you do the upload, in return there will be a `Key` returned too.  You'll see the `Key` would be the the whole path except the bucket name there